# Check if a cell value in a row exceeds a certain value

Tags: vba, excel

I want to check in excel whether any cell value in a given row (e.g. row 6) exceeds 40. I wrote this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Rows(6)
        If cell.Value > 40 Then MsgBox "You exceeded 40 in cell: " & cell.Address & ". Please correct your input!"
    Next cell

End Sub
```

But it gives me an error message

> Runtime error 13, Type mismatch.

Could you please advise? Thanks.

Comment: Which line does the error get raised?

Comment: It might be quicker to use MAX to see what the largest value is and then MATCH to find that cell if it's over 40

Comment: "For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Rows(6)" this is looking for cells in a collection of Rows. Try looking through a Cells collection.
"For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Rows(6).cells"

Comment: I would suggest that you do not test the whole row at every change in the sheet.

Comment: Consider:  What happens if `Cell.Value` is a Text String?  Try using an `IsNumeric` check before you do the `.Value` comparison

Comment: Also, if you use `Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange,ActiveSheet.Rows(6))` instead of `ActiveSheet.Rows(6)` you will skip checking a *lot* of unused cells on the row.  And `WorksheetFunction.CountIf`can be used first as a null-hypothesis ("If there are no cells with values over 40, I do not need to check each cell individually")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get every cell, change your `for`-loop to

```
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Rows(6).Cells
```

However, this will check the complete 6th row every time you change *anything* *anywhere* in the sheet. I guess it would be better to simply check the value of `Target` - this is the cell that is currently modified by the user.

**Update**
You could change your routine to

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If target.row = 6 && Target.Value > 40 Then 
        MsgBox "You exceeded 40 in target: " & target.Address & ". Please correct your input!"
    endif
End Sub
```

But if you simply want to prevent that the user enters some value greater than 40, you can easily archive this without VBA by using *data validation*:

Mark row 6, 
choose *Data -> Data Validation ->  Data Validation*

Enter for example "Whole number" (or decimal if you want to allow comma values), "less than or equal to" and 40 as maximum.

Comment: Yes that would be even better. Can you help me how to modify the code to do that?

Comment: Updated my answer